# Playing with Assembly without OS details

Tags: assembly, x86

I sometimes like to play with inline assembly in C(++) to learn more about it and easily interact with it. I looked into tutorials for assemblers like NASM, but it seems you have to pay attention to a lot of OS specific details to do just about anything.

Is there a way to play with assembly where I can just write simple functions and call them from C or something like that? Perhaps an assembler with object files as output?

Basically I'm interested in learning how to turn problems into low level instructions, I don't want to deal with the boilerplate code to print messages to the screen and all that.

Note that I'm not intending to write actual programs in assembly language. I know compilers do a much better job at it than I ever will. I'm just doing it for fun, essentially solving puzzles.

Comment: write your code in .s file and call it from main (gcc).

Comment: You can also use the -S flag to look at the assembler output of source code.  Using the assembler view in a debugger can also help.

Comment: Also, if you're doing this mostly for poking around (e.g. comparing C and asm implementations), you might want to consider using inline assembler: http://www.ibiblio.org/gferg/ldp/GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO.html . The GCC (not to mention AT&T) syntax takes some getting used to, but it is convenient to use C variables for exchanging data with the asm block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be interested in following [Paul Carter's PC Assembly Tutorial](http://www.drpaulcarter.com/pcasm/). It's for NASM and pretty much any C compiler (gcc, Open Watcom, Borland's, Microsoft's).